# On-the-fly Textfile template engine

Tags: filesystems, fuse

Is there a dynamic/on-the-fly textfile template engine that works on the filesystem level, e.g. via fuse, in a similar fashion to web-server html template engines?

Imagine you have, e.g. a `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` AP configuration file like so

```
# On-the-fly AP configuration for any interface
interface={{dev}}
ssid="AwesomeNetwork-{{dev}}"
...
```

Now I mount the `/etc/hostapd/` folder (or even just a single file) with my cool (fuse) fs to `/etc/hostapd-dyn`:

```
mount -t template-fuse /etc/hostapd /etc/hostapd-dyn
```

And the file `/etc/hostapd-dyn/hostapd.conf/dev=wlp0s2` would now contain

```
# On-the-fly AP configuration for any interface
interface=wlp0s2
ssid="AwesomeNetwork-wlp0s2"
...
```

Such a fs would allow to have dynamic configuration files where you might not even know in advance some of its values but you don't have the possibility to create the file dynamically by piping it through a file preprocessor/`awk`/`sed`/...

E.g. when defining dynamic `-@.service` `systemd` services you could use the dynamic variable to actually modify file content of a configuration file used in a `ExecStart=` statement. (Well, you could always prepend another `ExecStart=` command that creates the configuration file and then use the just created config file in the next line. But that wouldn't be as elegant and infeasibel in some situations.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a haskell project called "dotfs" that does something like what you're describing. This may be defunct, however.

It would be easy to put something together in python using fusepy. I've attached a gist (based on fusepy-base) which does almost what you're asking, by simply running the contents of each file through a bash echo, and expanding everything accordingly. This way you can also have dynamic input from other programs, via $().

[gleachkr/fusething.py](https://gist.github.com/gleachkr/8b4de1dc627726a383d008bff8cc7ef8)

If you want to tweak it, you can just fiddle with the rewrite functions at the top to do a more specific (or safer, that might be a good idea) kind of variable expansion.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually working on a go implementation, using fuse and a mustache parser and go's own template parser :)